# Ansible: How to maintain --extra-vars into two sub-playbooks when disconnection occurs?

Tags: ansible

The playbook I am developping should run after authentication on a single host (hostA) specified in command line with parameter (--extra-vars)
eg: [ansible-playbook main.yaml -e "variable_host=hostA"]

This main playbook includes a part1 and a part2 and it is expected that the hostA will disconnect the ansible session due to a reboot between part1 and part2.

Two solutions have been unsuccesfully tried:

**First solution:** (with include_tasks for each part: The first part1 is successfully processed on hostA, but the second part2 fails. This is due to a connection issue, because the part2 expects user/pwd. The vars_prompt seems to only be available for the part1 only)

> main.yaml

hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('All-host')}}"

vars_prompt:

```
- name: ADMUSER
  prompt: Username
  private: no
- name: ADMPASS
  prompt: password
  private: yes
```

tasks:

```
- name: ==> Part1
  include_tasks: TEST1.yaml      
- name: ==> Part2
  include_tasks: TEST2.yaml
```

**Second solution:** (with import_playbook for each part: First part1 is successfully processed. The second connection to the part2 is successful, but the part2 runs on all the hosts. The part2 should only run on hostA. 
The host variables is not overriden by --extra-vars)

> main.yaml

- import_playbook: playbook1.yaml
- import_playbook: playbook2.yaml

> playbook1.yaml

hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('All-host')}}"

vars_prompt:

```
- name: ADMUSER
  prompt: Username
  private: no
- name: ADMPASS
  prompt: password
  private: yes
```

tasks:

```
- nameA1:xxxx
- nameB1:xxxx
```

> playbook2.yaml

hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('All-host')}}"

vars_prompt:

```
- name: ADMUSER
  prompt: Username
  private: no
- name: ADMPASS
  prompt: password
  private: yes
```

tasks:

```
- nameA2:xxxx
- nameB2:xxxx
```

So, is there a solution to maintain the --extra-vars for hostA for part1 and part2 even if a disconnection occurs?
Note I am not in favor of a solution which modifies the config file "hosts" to restrict the playbook to a single host.
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally !!!

It works with the second solution, but instead of to restrict the host with extra-variables, I 've run the playbook with --limit "hostA"

Happy 2019.